# Align objective value variable

Tags: optidef

```
Z(p) = \begin{mini}|l|
{x}{c^T x}{}{}
\addConstraint{Ax}{\geq b}
\addConstraint{Dx}{\geq d}
\addConstraint{x}{\in \mathbb{Z}}
\end{mini}
```

How do I get the Z(p) to be aligned properly?

Answer (score 3):

By using `mini!` and the [optidef](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/optidef/optidef.pdf) package examples it seems this is a result being sought:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}|s|[2]<b>
{x}{c^T \, x}
{\label{eq:Example1}}
{Z(p) =}
\addConstraint{Ax}{\geq b}
\addConstraint{Dx}{\geq d}
\addConstraint{x}{\in \mathbb{Z}}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an AMS-related structure (with or without equation numbering):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\[
  Z(p) = \begin{aligned}[t]
         \min_x~ & c^T x \\
    \text{s.t.}~ & \begin{aligned}[t]
      Ax &\geq b, \\
      Dx &\geq d, \\
       x &\in \mathbb{Z}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{aligned}
\]

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{alignat}{2}
    Z(p) ={}&      \min_x \rlap{~$c^T x$} \\
            & \text{s.t.} & Ax &\leq b, \\
            &             & Dx &\leq d, \\
            &             &  x &\in \mathbb{Z}
  \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```